# SQL "partition by" similar feature in Python/R

Tags: python, sql, r, pandas, dplyr

Is there any packages either in R (data.table/dplyr) or in Python, that can do SQL code below in some consistent and straightforward way?

Can you share some examples of doing it?

Example of what I need:

**My input data-frame (CSV, sep - ";", headers - True) :**

```
articule;group;is_new;ammount
1;fruits;1;100
2;fruits;1;200
3;fruits;1;300
4;fruits;0;400
5;frozen;0;500
6;frozen;0;600
7;frozen;0;700
8;frozen;1;800
```

**My expected output (CSV, sep - ";", headers - True):**

```
articule;group;is_new;ammount;sum_by_group;sum_by_group_is_new;result
1;fruits;1;100;1000;600;0.60
2;fruits;1;200;1000;600;0.60
3;fruits;1;300;1000;600;0.60
4;fruits;0;400;1000;400;0.40
5;frozen;0;500;2600;1800;0.69
6;frozen;0;600;2600;1800;0.69
7;frozen;0;700;2600;1800;0.69
8;frozen;1;800;2600;800;0.31
```

**My code in SQL:**

```
select a.*, sum_by_group_is_new / sum_by_group result from (

select a.*, 
sum(ammount) over (partition by group) sum_by_group,
sum(ammount) over(partition by group, is_new) sum_by_group_is_new 
from input_data_frame a

) a;
```

Best regards

Comment: Pandas [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) might be helpful. Can you add some sample input and output data to your question?

Comment: I've added one example. May you look at this, please?

Comment: Please add the example as text (not an image) so we can copy it into python (or sql fiddle) and get the data frame / sql table. Also, please post both input AND expected output.

Comment: I've added input and expected data-frames, please look at this

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `transform` method with `groupby` in this case. It *sort of* works like SQL's `partition by`

```
df['sum_by_group'] = df.groupby('group').ammount.transform(sum)

df['sum_by_group_is_new'] = df.groupby(['group', 'is_new']).ammount.transform(sum)

df['result'] = df.sum_by_group_is_new / df.sum_by_group
```

this gave me the following output data frame.

```
   articule   group  is_new  ammount  sum_by_group  sum_by_group_is_new    result
0         1  fruits       1      100          1000                  600  0.600000
1         2  fruits       1      200          1000                  600  0.600000
2         3  fruits       1      300          1000                  600  0.600000
3         4  fruits       0      400          1000                  400  0.400000
4         5  frozen       0      500          2600                 1800  0.692308
5         6  frozen       0      600          2600                 1800  0.692308
6         7  frozen       0      700          2600                 1800  0.692308
7         8  frozen       1      800          2600                  800  0.307692
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  I wrote this in Dplyr and got :         df %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(by_group = sum(ammount)) %>% group_by(group, is_new) %>% mutate(by_group_is_new = sum(ammount)) %>% mutate(result = by_group_is_new / by_group)

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

Here is what you could do with R:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(
  articule = seq(8),
  group = rep(c("fruits", "frozen"), each = 4),
  is_new = c(rep(c(1, 0), each = 3), 0, 1),
  ammount = seq(100, 800, by = 100)
)

DT[, sum_by_group := sum(ammount), by = group]
DT[, sum_by_group_is_new := sum(ammount), by = .(group, is_new)]
DT[, result := sum_by_group_is_new / sum_by_group]

print(DT)
```

[image]